# NameError: name 'showimg' is not defined - this error is always showing even though it seems to be defined?? have i missed something?

Tags: python, image, camera

I am a complete beginner with coding and needed to code a few lines of code for getting pictures from a USB camera for a research project that i am responsible for. admittingly i took help of a few source codes from a few blogs online, they did show a couple of errors but most of them were resolved except this one that keeps popping up no matter what i do. does anyone have any idea where exactly the problem could be arising from? all the errors in the previous lines of code seem to be dealt with. I really need to get this right as this project decides my bacheklor thesis

the following was the code that i used, even though i am really really dumb with this stuff:
`

```
#new camera code

    import cv2
    import imutils 
    import time 
    #loop for taking picture and saving 
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
    frame = cap.read() 
    def takePicture(): 
    global showimg
   (frame) = cap.read()
   showimg=frame
   return image
   cv2.imshow('image', img)
   cv2.imshow('img1',showimg)  # display the captured image
   cv2.waitKey(1)
   time.sleep(0.3) # Wait 300 miliseconds
   image ='C:/Users/whale/Desktop/REMOVE/capture.png'
   cv2.imwrite(image, frame)
   img = cv2.imread('no-such-file.jpg', 0)
   cap.release()


   print(takePicture())
```

`

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. At the moment we can try to guess what you wanted to write, but we can't be sure.

Comment: After the edit the indentation still is wrong. Nothing after the function definition `def takePicture():` is indented (so we cannot know what the body of the function is) and you switch from the standard indentation of 4 spaces per level to 3 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- The `takePicture()` function is not returning anything. It needs to return `showimg` instead of `image`.
- The line `global showimg (frame) = cap.read()` should be changed to `global showimg, frame; frame = cap.read()`.
- The line `img = cv2.imread('no-such-file.jpg', 0)` should be removed as it is not being used and it may cause confusion.
- The line `print(takePicture())` should be changed to `takePicture()` as the function already displays the image.

Here's the correct code:

```
#new camera code
import cv2
import imutils
import time

#loop for taking picture and saving
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def takePicture():
    global showimg, frame
    frame = cap.read()
    showimg = frame
    cv2.imshow('image', showimg) # display the captured image
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    time.sleep(0.3) # Wait 300 miliseconds
    image ='C:/Users/whale/Desktop/REMOVE/capture.png'
    cv2.imwrite(image, frame)
    return showimg

takePicture()

cap.release()
```

Comment: Better still, don't use `global` at all, as it leads to inflexible and unmanageable code. Functions should get the values they need via parameters and return them with `return`.

Comment: the code should be able to save the image and display it right? it doesn't show any errors thankfully but doesn't quite save the image or display it either... I double checked the location to be sure too but there isn't any error there, could there be another problem with the code elsewhere maybe? thank you so much once again

Comment: thank you so much! the errors in the code are atleast resolved but there seems to be a completely new one now which is unique to raspberry pi- /tmp/geany_run_script_N7B4Z1.sh: 7: ./seconddraftDSA: Permission denied

I have no idea where this arises from